# AndroidX Error: Both old and new data binding packages are available in dependencies.I am upgrading a flutter project to AndroidX

Tags: android, flutter, androidx

I am getting the error after AndoirdX upgrade.

```
android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: failure, see logs for details.
AndroidX Error: Both old and new data binding packages are available in 
dependencies Make sure you've setup jettifier 
for any data binding dependencies and also set android.useAndroidX=true
```

I already have

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in my `gradle.properties`

Comment: found any solution ? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @MohamedElloumi Yes, you have to disable the data binding in build.gradle  file `` dataBinding {
        enabled = false
    }``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this error by disabling databinding in  build.gradle file

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I discovered that some layout files importing constraint layout from AndroidX and other layout files from android.support .

Changed all of them to use the android.support and problem solved.